# How to seed data in Elixir Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I generated a basic Phoenix API app.

```
mix phx.new app
```

I created a postgres database: `app_dev`

I generated the following database Schema:

```
mix phx.gen.json Items Item items name:string
```

Now, I want to seed data for the project.

I go to `priv/seed.exs` and I do not exactly understand the Syntax that is being asked for.

```
# Inside the script, you can read and write to any of your
# repositories directly:
#
#     App.Repo.insert!(%App.SomeSchema{})
#
# We recommend using the bang functions (`insert!`, `update!`
# and so on) as they will fail if something goes wrong.
```

I looked online for a few different examples and nothing worked.

I tried:

```
App.Repo.insert!(%App.Items{name: "we are the world"})
```

I get the following error:

```
** (CompileError) priv/repo/seeds.exs:14: App.Items.__struct__/1 is undefined, cannot expand struct App.Items. Make sure the struct name is correct. If the struct name exists and is correct but it still cannot be found, you likely have cyclic module usage in your code
    (app 0.1.0) expanding struct: App.Items.__struct__/1
    priv/repo/seeds.exs:14: (file)
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: Try `App.Repo.insert!(%App.Items.Item{name: "we are the world"})`

Comment: What are the module names of your `Ecto` structs?  I.e. the modules where you have `use Ecto.Schema`

Comment: My syntax for submitting the data was not correct. Peaceful James is correct.